# Slide up Menu with animation

Tags: css, hover, overflow, css-position, transition

I've made this:

```
<div class="example">
    <div class="menuholder">
        <ul class="menu slide">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="Burgergemeinde">
                    Burger-gemeinde
                    <div class="rojo"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="Seniorenwohnungen">
                    Senioren-wohnungen
                    <div class="naranja"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="Burgerheim">
                    Burgerheim
                    <div class="amarillo"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="Schüür">
                    Schüür
                    <div class="violeta"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="Forst">
                    Forst
                    <div class="verde"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qQ39J/1/
The css code is inside here

My question is: Why works in Safari, but not in Firefox? Can anyone help?
Perhaps I have not written right the code.
This is too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JS fiddle demo where it works in firefox.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TBMcW/1/)

go through it might help you with the transitions.

Here's the css

```
#main
{
height:200px;
width:200px;
background-color:red;
-webkit-transition: height 0.9s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: height 0.9s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: height 0.9s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: height 0.9s ease-in-out;
transition: height 0.9s ease-in-out;
}

#main:hover
{
height:300px;    
}
```

Here's the css and it animates a div.

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

Check and if you cannot proceed to a successful result let me know . ill start editing your answer in the fiddle :)

Comment: vertical animation is required. your's is a down animation.